# ansible create local directory (master)

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I forgot how to create on localhost ( ansible svr ) directory.
I'am using my ansible server as cache to download file and to copy them after that to the remote hosts.

Here example of task and playbook

tasks

```
- name:  Create temp folder
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
  with_items:
    - /tmp/foo/
```

playbook

```
- hosts: foo

  roles:
   - foo
```

Tryed with this but doesn't work:

```
- name:  Create temp folder
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    remote_src: no
  with_items:
    - /tmp/foo/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution `delegate_to: localhost`

```
- name:  Create temp folder
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_items:
    - /tmp/foo/
```